# Cypress certificate issue

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, cypress

We are running a build pipeline on Azure DevOps. NPM install task fails with the following error:

```
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node index.js --exec install
npm ERR! Installing Cypress (version: 4.2.0)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 25l[11:02:24]  Downloading Cypress     [started]
npm ERR! [11:02:24]  Downloading Cypress     [failed]
npm ERR! 25hThe Cypress App could not be downloaded.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ----------
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/4.2.0?platform=win32&arch=x64
npm ERR! Error: certificate has expired
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! ----------
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Platform: win32 (10.0.20348)
npm ERR! Cypress Version: 4.2.0
npm ERR! 25h
```

Regarding the proxy issue, I don't believe it actually exists because I tried downloading on the agent that's running the build and everything works as expected.
Does anyone have experience with the second error about the expired certificate? What certificate is the error about?

Node version: 16.20.1
Cypress version: 4.2.0

Edit:
I tried updating Node and Cypress version but it did not help.

Edit 2:
The build is working fine locally.

Comment: Can i ask why are you using Cypress 4.2.0? 
Could you try with a more recent version?

Comment: You could use a Microsoft-hosted agent to check if the problem persists. If the issue does not occur on the Microsoft-hosted agent, the issue is related to the self-hosted agent. You can check if your agent is running locally against the same account when run directly on your local machine. Please ensure that the account of the agent has the necessary permissions. By the way, could you also provide details of your task in the pipeline to reproduce the issue?

Comment: You can also enable the variable “[system.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug)”(set the value to “true”) in your pipeline , then trigger a new pipeline and check the detailed logs.

Comment: I tried switching to a different agent and the issue persists. Regarding detailed logs, I couldn't find anything that wasn't the already. Lastly, regarding the task that I'm using, it's just NPM install with a custom registry. I have NPM cache clean task beforehand.